# SQL Error: "A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause." - while executing in Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, mssql-jdbc

**SQL Table - TABLE1**

Table1 contains three columns - **STORE_ID (PK,numeric(5,0), not null), ATTRB_NAME (PK,varchar(50), not null), PRDCT_NAME (varchar(50), not null)**.

STORE_ID value changes and ATTRB_NAME, PRDCT_NAME values are constant

Azure databricks notebook has been developed for executing the insert query which actually insert data to the above table. Store id is taken from a list. The following code has been executed:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

insertDataList = []
store_id_list = [210, 345]

for element in store_id_list:
  paramList = ['ATTRB_VAL','PRDCT_VAL']
  paramList.insert(0,element)
  insertDataList.append(tuple(paramList))

rows = insertDataList
values = ', '.join(map(str, rows))
insert_query = "(INSERT INTO [DB1].[dbo].[TABLE1] VALUES {}) b_alias".format(values)

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=insert_query, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Unfortunately, it is throwing the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A nested INSERT,
> UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement must have an OUTPUT clause.

I executed the script by reframing the insert query but it all ended up displaying the same error. May I know what needs to be done here? I'm a beginner in SQL. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your `INSERT` statement inside parenthesis (`()`)? Also why are you **injecting** the values, instead of properly parametrising your statement?

Comment: @Larnu The [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases) follows that format for query execution using python from azure-databricks. Values are injecting because, _store_id_list_ will be provided externally. So a row has to be created first from _store_id_list_ and _paramList_, then injected to the insert query. _store_id_list_ can have n elements.

Comment: None of the `INSERT` statements in that document are inside parenthesis... As for why you are injecting, your comment implies the table has a dynamic number of columns; that's impossible. **Parametrise** your statement.

Comment: Kindly help me to reframe it. When I'm executing the INSERT query without parenthesis, it is giving Incorrect Syntax error.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis and parametrise... `INSERT INTO [dbo].[TABLE1] VALUES(?,?)` (`?` are placeholders for parameters, which you'll need to pass per `pyspark`'s syntax). I also remove the database name, as that should be defined in the connection string.

Comment: How come you're trying to use `read` to `insert` data? Have you considered trying [`write`](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#jdbc-writes) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all suggestions. I was able to insert data successfully when I tried the following code snippet.

```
for rec in rows:
      df = spark.createDataFrame([(rec[0], rec[1], rec[2])],['STORE_ID', 'ATTRB_NAME', 'PRDCT_NAME']).cache()
      df.write.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl,table='TABLE1',mode='append',properties=connectionProperties)
```